# JavaScript While Statement Continuing to Run when Condition is False

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to JavaScript and web development so I apologize if this has already been answered. I am making a webpage with an image carousel. I have added buttons to go to the next and previous images as well as an automatic scrolling feature; these both work as intended. The issue comes in when I am trying to disable the automatic scrolling upon the pressing of either of the buttons. When I press a button, the automatic scrolling continues. My code is below.

```
<script>
            var carousel = document.getElementById("carousel");
            var width = carousel.offsetWidth;
            var scrollDelay = 2.5; //Amount of time between each slide in the carousel (seconds)
            var interrupted = false;

            function next() {
                carousel.scrollBy({ 
                    left: width, 
                    behavior: 'smooth' 
                });
                interruped = true;
            }
            function back() {
                carousel.scrollBy({ 
                    left: (width * -1), 
                    behavior: 'smooth'
                });
                interruped = true;
            }
            
            var i = 0;
            while (i < 100 && !interrupted) {
                i++;
                autoScroll();
            }
                
            function autoScroll() {
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        next();
                    }, scrollDelay * 1000 * i)
            }
        </script>
```

I believe my issue has something to do with the while statement. When I press the button, it changes the value of interrupted to true, which should end the loop, but it does not. Does anyone know why this might be happening?

Comment: I don't see how this `while` loop would be continuing to run at all after the page has rendered.  It only runs once when the page loads, then never again.

Comment: @David the while loop sets up 100 timers, and nothing ever cancels the timers.

Comment: What the OP is seeing is that the timeouts established by the while loop continue to auto-scroll the carousel. They're interpreting that to mean the while loop is continuing to run.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be under the impression that `setTimeout` will pause execution so the next iteration of the `while` loop won't happen under after the timeout occurs, at which point you're expecting the call to `next()` will have set `interrupted` to true.

That's not how `setTimeout` works: it queues up a task in the background, and allows execution to continue, so all `100` iterations of your while loop happen right off the bat. A quick-and-dirty fix would be to check `interrupted` in your timeout:

```
            function autoScroll() {
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        if(!interrupted) 
                            next();
                    }, scrollDelay * 1000 * i)
            }
```

But that won't solve all your problems: `next()` sets `interrupted` to `true` regardless of whether it was invoked automatically or by a button press. You'll need to add some more logic to address issues like that. I'd also suggest looking at `setInterval` to scroll every second rather than calling `setTimeout` many times.